# How to get random IP from docker network?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-container, docker-network

I want to automate container deployment with random IP from custom Docker network, however, the container should get a free IP first of all, and second, I should be able to get a list of free IP's from the Docker custom network.

Is any of this doable?

Comment: Usually you don't need to manually interact with the Docker networking setup at this level; if you do nothing, Docker will assign you a free IP address on its own.

Comment: @David Maze Is there a command for assigning an IP without a value?

Comment: If you do absolutely nothing (beyond possibly `docker network create some-network` and then attaching your container `--net some-network`), Docker will take care of all of the IP management for you.  (And in fact you should usually ignore this as an implementation detail.)  Do you need something different from the default behavior?

Comment: @David Maze Thanks for your answers. In fact the only thing necessary was to let docker pick an available IP from  a custom network.